# Is it a bad practise to store Session data in spring boot, using @SessionScope?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a simple spring boot application, in which I need to manage user session, so to understand session maintenance in spring boot I created this little demo,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api") 
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    Students students;
    
    @PostMapping("/saveStudentInfo")
    public String saveStudentInfo(@RequestBody Students stud) {
        students.setId(stud.getId());
        students.setStudentName(stud.getStudentName());
        students.setSchoolInfo(stud.getSchoolInfo());
        return "Saved Sucessfully";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getStudentSchool")
    public School getStudentSchool()
    {
        return students.getSchoolInfo();
    }
    
}

@Component
@SessionScope
public class School {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    
    // Getter+Setter+Constructor+toString
}

@Component
@SessionScope
public class Students {

    private int id;
    private String studentName;
    private School schoolInfo;
    
    // Getter+Setter+Constructor+toString
}
```

**Json to Test**

```
{
    "id":1,
    "studentName":"Alan Walker",
    "schoolInfo":{
        "id":101,
        "name":"St. John's",
        "address": "Street 5"
    }
}
```

Now using this kind of structure,

When I first make post request, to save data in `Students` object it gets saved, then when I retrieve it using get a request I receive the data successfully.

Here, I required to store student information in session, so I annotated them using @SessionScope.

Is this a bad practise **or** is there any other way to do this. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: REST should be stateless.

Comment: But then how, I am retrieving my data back? and why spring has provided this

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html

Comment: @John - I believe OldProgrammer has confounded two conceptual, academic Ideas. Yes, REST services are supposed to be stateless. So the question is often, "how do secure, through authentication and access control, the REST API"? There are a number of answers, and using Sessions is a completely legitimate answer. The key to keep in mind, and maybe the mistake OldProgrammer picked up on, is that your combining your session management code with your REST controller. Don't do that - keep your session management completely separate from the REST code. Then your REST impl is stateless - but secured.

Comment: Your question, "_What is the correct way to maintain a session on spring boot application_" - is rhetorical - Why do you believe you need sessions in your spring-boot app?

Comment: So why spring has provided @SessionScope or SpringSession like annotations and API respectively?

Comment: Why `School` is a singleton ?? ;)

Comment: @John for statefull MVC applications.